# Convert some cells in a column from date format to text

Tags: excel

Given a column like this:

```
  Column A
1 4
2 Blank
3 Blank
4 3
5 blank
6 2NDF
7 Blank
8 blank
9 1/2/2014 <-- Date value I need to change to a text value: "1-2"
10 blank
11 5/1/2014 <-- Date value I need to change to a text value: "5-1"
12 blank

...
```

I need to find a way to programmatically change each cell that contains a date value like in rows 9 and 11 into a text value the equivalent of the numeric month followed by a dash follwed by a numeric day. I have 24,000 rows. Doing a find and replace is not practical. I cannot change the format of the entire column because rows like 1 and 4 get converted and I don't want those to get converted.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Did you import a file in excel and those values got automatically converted?

Comment: It is somebody else's .xlsx spreadsheet I'm opening. It appears they had the wrong data type selected for this column. It should have been text. There's nothing I can do to change the original file.

Comment: The problem is that dates are also numbers (as you noted `41763`) and there are other numbers in the column as well. 41763 is indeed the number of days after 1/1/1900 (though there's one day anomaly in that date system). So if you have `4`, it'll probably also turn into 4th Jan 1900, which would give you `4-1` if you try to do something on the whole column.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column B and use the function

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A1))),MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1))&"-"&DAY(DATEVALUE(A1)),A1)
```

Comment: Try `TEXT(A1, "m-d")` instead :p

Comment: Brett, close. But when I have a date in the field it is returning a value such as 41763, which I assume is days since 1901. Not sure what the deal is. It seems like it is evaluating the "false" value, a1. When I replace the false value with "blah" it returns "blah".

Answer (score 0):

OK, I achieved the result I wanted by splitting out three "if" tests (similar to what Brett suggested) into 3 additional columns. Each column had its separate "if" test and built on the column before it. Here are the if tests:

```
=IF(N5>40000,MONTH(N5)&"-"&DAY(N5),N5) # sets format I want and skip cells that are low integers and not dates
=IF(O5=0,"",O5) # Sets cells with "0" in them to blank
=IF(ISERROR(P5),N5,P5) # fixes cells that were originally text and that produced errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that in the OP the data seems to be in ColumnA starting in Row1 a single formula such as:

```
=IF(OR(A1<40000,ISTEXT(A1)),A1,MONTH(A1)&"-"&DAY(A1))
```

and copied down would seem adequate.